# Getting text from HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the current "5 minute trend price" from the [website](https://rrtp.comed.com/live-prices/) of my electricity provider using Python2.7 and BeautifulSoup4.

The xpath is: `xpath = "//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/p[1]"`

or

```
<div class="instant prices">
  <p class="price">
    "5.2"  # this is what I'm ultimately after
    <small>¢</small>
    <strong> per kWh </strong>
  </p>
```

I've tried a myriad of different ways of getting the **"5.2"** value and have successfully been able to drill down to the "instant prices" object, but can't get anything from it.

My current code looks like this:
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
url = "https://rrtp.comed.com/live-prices/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
#print soup

instantPrices = soup.findAll('div', 'instant prices')
print instantPrices
```

...and the output is:

```
[<div class="instant prices">
</div>]
[]
```

No matter what, it appears that the "instant prices" object is empty even though I can clearly see it when inspecting the element in Chrome. **Any help would be hugely appreciated!** Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this data is generated via Javascript when the browser renders the website. Thats why this information is not there when you download the source with urllib. What you can do is directly query the backend:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import re

>>> url = "https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=instant"
>>> s = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
"<p class='price'>4.5<small>&cent;</small><strong> per kWh </strong></p><p>5-minute Trend Price 7:40 PM&nbsp;CT</p>\r\n"

>>> float(re.findall("\d+.\d+", s)[0])
4.5
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the answer, elyase. Works fine. I'm clearly not too familiar with HTML or JS, yet. How did you identify that the data was generated with JS and back-end URL?

Comment: For example in Chrome you will see a difference between "View Source Code" and "Inspect Element". The source code is what you get from the server, Inspect Element shows also what was generated via JavaScript on the clients browser.